# Is there a way to Sort Comments History by Descending order?

Tags: magento-1.7, sales

This might seem like a silly questoin so I apologies if it does but I am looking to change the Sort order for Comments history in Magento Sales/Order_View Comments History Tab.

Currently the Comments are listed in Ascending Order but I would like to list them in Descending order without having to touch any Core files of course...

The question I would like to as is Where? and How?

Thanks in advance...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The status history collection is pulled from the `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` object in a method called `getStatusHistoryCollection`. That method is defined as:

```
/**
 * Enter description here...
 *
 * @return Mage_Sales_Model_Entity_Order_Status_History_Collection
 */
public function getStatusHistoryCollection($reload=false)
{
    if (is_null($this->_statusHistory) || $reload) {
        $this->_statusHistory = Mage::getResourceModel('sales/order_status_history_collection')
            ->setOrderFilter($this)
            ->setOrder('created_at', 'desc')
            ->setOrder('entity_id', 'desc');

        if ($this->getId()) {
            foreach ($this->_statusHistory as $status) {
                $status->setOrder($this);
            }
        }
    }
    return $this->_statusHistory;
}
```

As you can see in `setOrder('created_at', 'desc')` **by default it is sorted in descending order**, and has been since Magento 1.0 (perhaps longer, I don't have access to prior releases).

So, either you mean ASCENDING order (oldest first) OR you have an extension conflict that is rewriting this method. If it's the former - create a model rewrite of `Mage_Sales_Model_Order` and rewrite only the `getStatusHistoryCollection` method, fetching the parent and applying a new sort:

```
public function getStatusHistoryCollection($reload=false)
{
    $_history = parent::getStatusHistoryCollection($reload);
    $_history->setOrder('created_at', 'asc');
    return $_history;
}
```

Otherwise, you'll have to track down the offending module / rewrite that's causing your undesired sort order.

**Edit:**

Apparently I can't read! For posterity I'm keeping the above because it's good stuff anyhow.

The **history tab** on the sales order view indeed is sorted in ascending fashion because it contains *all* of the histories for all of the comments on every transaction item (Credit Memo, Invoice, Order, Shipments, etc.). This pseudo-collection assembled in `getFullHistory` is gathered by shoving all transaction type comments into a large array and calling a custom sort method on it.

To sort this, you need to rewrite the sort function used in the `usort` method of the class `Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Sales_Order_View_Tab_History`. It should be as easy as:

```
private static function _sortHistoryByTimestamp($a, $b)
{
   return -1 * (parent::_sortHistoryByTimestamp($a, $b));
}
```

Which should force the sort order to the opposite direction. Sorry for any confusion.